# Easy way of proving continuity of a convex function

Tags: analysis

Is there an easy and fast way to prove that a convex function $f : I \to \mathbb{R}, \, I \subset \mathbb{R}$ an interval, is continuous? All the proofs that I know are very long and technical. Thanks in advance for any answer!